# Sum $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{3^{i-1}}{2^{i-2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

### $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{3^{i-1}}{2^{i-2}}$$

Currently, I am just iterating `i` from `1` to `n` but this seems to be unnecessary as if we could have a closed form of this sum, then we may achieve constant-time computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite the sum as

$$2\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^i$$

then use formulas for [finite geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) to calculate the result.

Comment: Good idea, but there's a typo

Comment: @Fakemistake What typo?

Comment: Oh my god. You made it so simple.

Comment: Or am i wrong? The number in front of the summation sign must be a 2?

Comment: yes. It should be 2

Answer (score 1):

It's a sum of the geometric progression:$$2\cdot\frac{\left(\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n-1\right)}{\frac{3}{2}-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Take out 1/2 common and use Geometric Progression.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression